# Is it possible to make the menu control open submenu only on click?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menuitem

Here is my code:

```
    <Menu>
        <Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemsPanel>

        <MenuItem Header="Level1 Test 1" >           
            <MenuItem Header="Level2 Test 1"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Level2 Test 2"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Level2 Test 3">
                <MenuItem Header="Level3 1"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Level3 2"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Level3 3">
                    <MenuItem Header="Level4 1"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Level4 2"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>    
    </Menu>
```

Currently, as you may know, hovering over the menu items with child elements opens the sub menu displaying those children. How can I get `<MenuItem Header="Level2 Test3">` to only open its sub menu by clicking on it, and not by hovering? Is there a way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WPF, but I guess you could attach to some kind of `OnHover` event and cancel it from argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 'IsMouseOver' is what you are looking for. Below is what I looked at when I ran into a similar issue.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/da54f9fc-068b-46fb-988f-b752d07ba1c5/making-ismouseover-open-submenu-items-consistently?forum=wpf

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know you could edit templates by right clicking on the control.